# Try to pass an object to a same template class to copy

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates

I work actually to understand the concept of template and implement a simple one. I manage to almost cases execpt one to code a constructor to copy an instance of same class.

```
#include <iostream>

// template <typename T>
template <class T>
class vec2 {
private:
    static int instance;
    T const x;
    T const y;
public:
    vec2() : x(0), y(0) {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
        vec2<T>::instance++;
        return;
    }

    vec2(T const &x, T const &y) : x(x), y(y) {
        std::cout << "Parametric constructor" << std::endl;
        vec2<T>::instance++;
        return;
    }

    vec2(vec2<T> const & src) {
        *this = src;
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
        vec2<T>::instance++;
        return;
    }

    ~vec2(){
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
        vec2<T>::instance--;
        return;
    }

    vec2 & operator=(vec2 const & rhs) {
        this->x = rhs.get_x();
        this->y = rhs.get_y();
        return *this;
    }

  // get
    static int get_instance() {
        return vec2<T>::instance;
    }

    T get_x() const {
        return this->x;
    }

    T get_y() const {
        return this->y;
    }
}; 

template <class T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, vec2<T> const & rhs) {
    out << "[ " << rhs.get_x() << ", " << rhs.get_y() << " ]";
    return out;
}

template <class T>
int vec2<T>::instance = 0;


int main() {
    vec2<float> a;
    vec2<int> b(21, 42);
    vec2<float> c(21.21f, 42.42f);
    vec2<bool> d(true, false);
    vec2<int> e(b);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << e << std::endl;

    std::cout << "a.get_x(): " << a.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a.get_y(): " << a.get_y() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "b.get_x(): " << b.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.get_y(): " << b.get_y() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "c.get_x(): " << c.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c.get_y(): " << c.get_y() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "d.get_x(): " << d.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d.get_y(): " << d.get_y() << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

here the error message, but I'm not expert te read it, and i don't understand what i must change in my code. So if anybody I have an idea to help a newbee in C++, that's can be awesome.

```
clang++  -std=c++11 -Wconversion *.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:24:2: error: constructor for 'vec2<int>' must explicitly initialize the
      const member 'x'
        vec2(vec2<T> const & src) {
        ^
main.cpp:72:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'vec2<int>::vec2'
      requested here
        vec2<int> e(b);
                  ^
main.cpp:9:10: note: declared here
        T const x;
                ^
main.cpp:24:2: error: constructor for 'vec2<int>' must explicitly initialize the
      const member 'y'
        vec2(vec2<T> const & src) {
        ^
main.cpp:10:10: note: declared here
        T const y;
                ^
main.cpp:38:11: error: cannot assign to non-static data member 'x' with
      const-qualified type 'const int'
                this->x = rhs.get_x();
                ~~~~~~~ ^
main.cpp:25:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'vec2<int>::operator='
      requested here
                *this = src;
                      ^
main.cpp:72:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'vec2<int>::vec2'
      requested here
        vec2<int> e(b);
                  ^
main.cpp:9:10: note: non-static data member 'x' declared const here
        T const x;
        ~~~~~~~~^
main.cpp:39:11: error: cannot assign to non-static data member 'y' with
      const-qualified type 'const int'
                this->y = rhs.get_y();
                ~~~~~~~ ^
main.cpp:10:10: note: non-static data member 'y' declared const here
        T const y;
        ~~~~~~~~^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates. If you declare a regular class with a `const` class member, and your constructor fails to initialize it, you'll get the same error. "`*this = src;`" will not work. x and y must be explicitly constructed, in the initialization section. For more information, see your C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sam Varshavchik said in the comments, the problem is that you don't initialize your const members in your copy-constructor. Here is the correct implementation:

```
vec2(vec2<T> const & src) : x(src.get_x()), y(src.get_y()) { //<-- initialization of const members
    std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    vec2<T>::instance++;
    return;
 }
```

Also, `*this = src;` does feel all kinds of wrong.

Answer (score 0):

here my original class code where i make a copy with `*this = src` and the result work great. So the question why that's work with regular `class` and not with the `template` ?
Plus I imagine the behavior with the regular class, the adress stay the same.
And the method to init all member can be complicated if the is a lot members variables in the class ?
`main.c`

```
#include "Vec2.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Vec2 a;
    Vec2 b(21,42);
    Vec2 c(a);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    std::cout << "c.get_x(): " << c.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c.get_y(): " << c.get_y() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "b.get_x(): " << b.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.get_y(): " << b.get_y() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "a.get_x(): " << a.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a.get_y(): " << a.get_y() << std::endl;
    a = b;
    std::cout << "a.get_x(): " << a.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a.get_y(): " << a.get_y() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`Vec2.cpp`

```
#ifndef VEC2_H
# define VEC2_H

#include <iostream>

class Vec2 {
public:
    Vec2(); // canonical
    Vec2(float const x, float const y);
    Vec2(Vec2 const &); // canonical
    ~Vec2();    // canonical

    Vec2 & operator=(Vec2 const & rhs);     // canonical

    static int get_instance();

    float get_x() const ;
    float get_y() const ;

private:
    static int instance;
    float x;
    float y;
}; 

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & out, Vec2 const & rhs);

#endif
```

`vec2.hpp`

```
#include "Vec2.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Vec2::Vec2() : x(0), y(0) {
    std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    Vec2::instance++;
    return;
}

Vec2::Vec2(float const x, float const y) : x(x), y(y) {
    std::cout << "Parametric constructor" << std::endl;
    Vec2::instance++;
    return;
}

Vec2::Vec2(Vec2 const & src) {
    *this = src;
    std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    Vec2::instance++;
    return;
}

Vec2::~Vec2() {
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    Vec2::instance--;
    return;
}

Vec2 & Vec2::operator=(Vec2 const & rhs) {
    this->x = rhs.get_x();
    this->y = rhs.get_y();
    return *this;
}

int Vec2::get_instance(){
    return Vec2::instance;
}

float Vec2::get_x() const {
    return this->x;
}

float Vec2::get_y() const {
    return this->y;
}

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & out, Vec2 const & rhs) {
    out << "[ " << rhs.get_x() << ", " << rhs.get_y() << " ]";
    return out;
}


int Vec2::instance = 0;
```

Comment: The problem isn't because of regular and template classes. In this implementation, your `x` and `y` memebers aren't `const`. Make them `const` and you will get the same error. Also, `*this = src` will call the (default-defined) copy-assignment operator, which is why it may work, but it's not how you should go about it.

Comment: that's for all this informations. I use this method because in the tutovideo of 42 school the teacher use this method, but may be it's not really optimum. thx for your lights.